# How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to  get the  1st of the month following the date the person turns 70. How to achive this in SQL

i am calculating age using the formula

```
DECLARE @Date_of_birth DATETIME = '1915-10-02 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @AGE INT
SELECT @AGE =  FLOOR((CAST (GETDATE() AS INTEGER) - CAST(@Date_of_birth AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) 

IF(@AGE > 70)

   How to find the first of the month following the date ??
IF (@AGE >80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datediff to calculate their age, and then date add to find their 70th birthday. To find the first of the month afterwards, you can use the Month and Year functions.

```
create table #people (name varchar(30), birthdate date)

insert into #people
values ('Bob', '07/08/1976'), ('Tasha','05/30/1996'),('April','04/01/1971')

--This will give you everyone's age
select DATEDIFF(YY,birthdate,GETDATE()) as age
from #people

--This will give you the first month following the date that they turn 70
select Name, DATEADD(yy,70,birthdate) as [70thBday], convert(varchar,month(dateadd(m,1,DATEADD(yy,70,birthdate)))) + '/01/' + convert(varchar,YEAR(dateadd(m,1,DATEADD(yy,70,birthdate))))
from #people
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @dob datetime = '1954-06-08'
declare @age int = 70

select DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, DATEADD(yy, @age, @dob)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dateadd function like this

```
select dateadd(d,1 - datepart(d,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(yy,70",,@Date_of_birth)),dateadd(m,1,dateadd(yy,70",,@Date_of_birth)))
```

You can break down this query like this

```
declare @BD_70 date = dateadd(yy,70",,@Date_of_birth)
declare @Nxt_Month_70 = dateadd(m,1,@BD_70 date)
declare @First_Of_Month_70 = dateadd(d,1 - datepart(d,@Nxt_Month_70),@Nxt_Month_70)
```

Basically, you add 70 year, find next month and replace the day to the first of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would calculate age base on current date.

```
select case 
            when cast(getdate() as date) = cast(dateadd(year, (datediff(year, '1996-09-09', getdate())), '1996-09-09') as date)
                then dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, 0, getdate()))
            else dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
        end as MemberAge
go
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I calculate the age:

SELECT DATEDIFF(yy, [DateOfBirth], GETDATE()) + (CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(MONTH, [DateOfBirth]) < 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Age FROM [User]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function.(Support `MySQL`, `Apache Doris`)

**Example:**

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,'1996-09-09',now()) as age;
```